# AutoRestart error in SQL Server logs (reason: Access is denied)

Tags: sql-server

My instance of SQL Server 2008 SP1 crashed, which is a separate issue, and I see the following set of messages in the SQL Server Agent log:

```
[139] AutoRestart: Attempting to restart the MSSQLSERVER service (attempt #1)...
[368] AutoRestart: Unable to restart the MSSQLSERVER service (reason: Access is denied)
```

Is there an authoritative place that describes what permissions should be assigned to a domain account that the SQL Server Agent runs as?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283811

If the account that the MSSQLServer service is going to start with is one of the following two accounts, you must add the startup account for the MSSQLServer and the SQLServerAgent services, or both, to the SQL Server sysadmin)role, and grant the [Domain\NTaccount] user a logon to SQL Server.